# How to read from parcel

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I thought I understood how to read/write from a parcel, but now I'm getting stuck. In one of my parcelable objects, I have this function

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(7);
    int testInt = dest.readInt();
    Log.d("test","INT = " + testInt);
}
```

which gets run correctly when the state of the activity is saved. This outputs

```
INT = 0
```

which I assume is because I'm not correctly writing / reading to the parcel. Or maybe you're not allowed to write and read immediately. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is some other code writing the int "0" to the parcel before you write your 7?

Comment: No, that's the entire code. I assume I get "0" because that is the default value for an int

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to write to the `Parcel` in the `writeToParcel` method, and read from the `Parcel` in the `Creator`'s `createFromParcel` method.

I'm not sure why you would want to read from a `Parcel` in a `writeToParcel` method, but if you do do that, you should not expect the most recently written `int` to be read first; the data is read in the same order it was written.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's completely useless to read and write in the writeToParcel function. I was just trying to test if I understood how it worked. But the fact that I got 0 seemed weird. I got 0 when I tried it in the createFromParcel function as well. So my question still isn't answered

Comment: @Bob In that case you need to show us a complete runnable example. It's hard to answer without seeing the methods in full and information about when and how the object is written to and read from the parcel.